# Computer restarts when fading into blank screen or suspending

Tags: 20.04, suspend, restart, firmware, toshiba-satellite

I just installed Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 today in my Toshiba Satellite L50-B.

I noticed that the computer restarts either when idling for a few minutes, which would supposedly lead to a blank screen, or when manually suspending it.

The on/off led initially turns off for a few seconds, but it quickly turns on again and the computer reboots from scratch.

I did have a problem when installing Ubuntu initially, I don't know if these issues might be related. The error message was something along the lines of (all I have is a phone picture with a few error lines, sorry for the lack of details):

```
[  0.080971] DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR, contact BIOS vendor for fixes
/dev/sda2: recovering journal
/dev/sda2: clean, ... (big number) files, ... (big number) blocks
[ 10.388988] Bluetooth: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[ 11.822854] kfd kfd: TOPAZ not supported in kfd
```

Upon reboot I chose the `Ubuntu (Advanced options)` (something like this) and then `Recovery mode`(again, something like this...) and it worked out fine. Since then I didn't face this error again when turning the computer on.

I'm sorry if didn't share enough information to diagnose what the problem might be. I'd be happy to provide more details if that's needed.

**EDIT**:

I just went through a few more tests which led to a few very weird results:

- I had previously tested if any errors would come up when logging out, but none did. Then I tried logging out and closing the notebook lid. The screen was still showing up in the other monitor I'm using, so I opened the lid to check what was going on. Upon opening the lid the computer shut down and restarted again.
- After restarting I decided I'd remove my second monitor to see if that was related to the error. As soon as I removed the HDMI cable from the notebook the notebook (hence disconnected the second monitor) the computer restarted.
- This time, upon re initialisation, the same `Firmware Bug` I pasted above showed up again. Then I manually rebooted the computer.
- I was then asked if I wanted to do a normal initialisation or choose advanced options, and I chose the latter. Then I chose the recovery mode again, and after recovering I went with the normal setup. The computer started just fine.
- Then I decided: "ok, I'm gonna check the Suspend mode now". Manually suspended and the computer "locked" into a screen showing the time. Then I tried logging in again and literally just after it the computer seemed to "sleep" (not sure if that's what the suspension is meant to be) into a black screen, with the power led slowly going on and off. When I tried to turn it on... an error.
- This time upon initialisation I faced a new error message:

```
[  25.389067] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_flip_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:45:pipe A] flip_done timed out
[  25.952180] amdgpu: VBIOS did not find boot engine clock value in dependency table. Using DPM level 0!
```

I got stuck here for a while, so I manually rebooted

- Then I went with the `Ubuntu (advanced options)` and `recovery mode` to initialise the computer, and here I am writing this comment.

**EDIT 2:**

When using the computer without a second monitor attached to it the computer is actually able to fade into blank screen. After unlocking it everything works fine. But, I still have problems with suspension. If I manually suspend the computer actually goes to suspension, but when I try to get out of it the computer restarts from scratch. This is then followed by an error when booting, which leads to me going through the Advanced options -> Recovery mode again, which works fine.

**EDIT 3:**

Turning the computer on now seems to lead to a boot failure 100% of the time. These are the system logs when filtering for errors and warnings:

```
fev 16 09:22:30 kernel: DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR [0x000000009d800000-0x000000009fffffff], contact BIOS vendor for fixes
fev 16 09:22:30 kernel: DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: Your BIOS is broken; bad RMRR [0x000000009d800000-0x000000009fffffff]
                        BIOS vendor: INSYDE Corp.; Ver: 2.00; Product Version: PSKTNA-02R016
fev 16 09:22:30 kernel: MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html for more details.
fev 16 09:22:30 kernel:  #3
fev 16 09:22:30 kernel: ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
fev 16 09:22:30 kernel: pci 0000:00:14.0: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
fev 16 09:22:30 kernel: pci 0000:00:14.0: PCI INT A: not connected
fev 16 09:22:30 kernel: platform eisa.0: EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard
fev 16 09:22:30 kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
fev 16 09:22:30 kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 2
fev 16 09:22:30 kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 3
fev 16 09:22:30 kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 4
fev 16 09:22:30 kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 5
fev 16 09:22:30 kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 6
fev 16 09:22:30 kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 7
fev 16 09:22:30 kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 8
fev 16 09:22:30 kernel: r8169 0000:08:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
fev 16 09:22:30 kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
fev 16 09:22:30 kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: PCI INT A: no GSI
fev 16 09:22:30 kernel: usb: port power management may be unreliable
```

When turning it on via Ubuntu (Advanced Options) -> Ubuntu Linux generic (Recovery Mode), which leads to a successful boot, these are the log files (now filtered only for errors due to lengthy output):

```
fev 16 09:23:53 kernel: [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x25 (or later)
fev 16 09:23:53 kernel: DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR [0x000000009d800000-0x000000009fffffff], contact BIOS vendor for fixes
fev 16 09:24:00 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
fev 16 09:24:00 kernel: [drm:amdgpu_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* VGACON disables amdgpu kernel modesetting.
fev 16 09:24:07 systemd[766]: /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/friendly-recovery failed with exit status 1.
fev 16 09:24:10 avahi-daemon[874]: chroot.c: open() failed: No such file or directory
fev 16 09:24:31 kernel: debugfs: File 'force_bredr_smp' in directory 'hci0' already present!
fev 16 09:24:36 gnome-session-binary[1149]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
fev 16 09:24:58 kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: HSW/BDW HD-audio HDMI/DP requires binding with gfx driver
fev 16 09:25:00 gdm-password][1569]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
```

Finally, these are the log files when suspending the computer, which leads to a system restart when trying to get out of it (filtered for the last 15 log messages):

```
fev 16 09:51:47 wpa_supplicant[835]: wlp7s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-100
fev 16 09:51:47 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1305]: dbus-daemon[1305]: [session uid=125 pid=1305] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.12' (uid=125 pid=1448 comm="/usr/libexec/gsd-sharing " label="unconfined")
fev 16 09:51:47 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1305]: dbus-daemon[1305]: [session uid=125 pid=1305] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
fev 16 09:51:47 gsd-sharing[1448]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
fev 16 09:51:47 gsd-sharing[1448]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
fev 16 09:51:47 gsd-sharing[1448]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
fev 16 09:51:47 gsd-sharing[1448]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
fev 16 09:51:47 nm-dispatcher[4275]: run-parts: failed to stat component /etc/network/if-post-down.d/avahi-daemon: No such file or directory
fev 16 09:51:47 wpa_supplicant[835]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp7s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
fev 16 09:51:47 gnome-shell[1853]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
fev 16 09:51:47 wpa_supplicant[835]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp7s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
fev 16 09:51:49 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
fev 16 09:51:49 systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
fev 16 09:51:49 systemd-sleep[4285]: Suspending system...
fev 16 09:51:49 kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
```

Finally, upon re-boot the cycle begins again: it fails the first time and I have to use the Advanced Options -> Recovery Mode option.

Comment: Read `man journalctl`. To see the system logs of the most recent shutdown, `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e`, most recent boot `sudo journalctl -b 0`.

Comment: Hi @waltinator, thanks for the heads-up. I'll do some good reading on the logs and eventually edit the question with something that seems off.

Comment: Thank yous and prediction of future actions, while they may be polite, add no information. Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.